# VSTS: Different Config Files (WCF endpoint addresses) for different environments using RM

Tags: wcf, web-config, azure-devops, ms-release-management

I have different projects that are consuming many WCF services. I am using VSTS to automate deployments. Those services target different URLs (endpoint addresses) based on the environment where they are going to be deployed.

I am trying to use web deploy with VSTS release management as suggested in this link:[WebDeploy with VSTS](http://blog.ehn.nu/2016/03/using-web-deploy-in-visual-studio-team-services-release-management///), which proposes to create:

- Parmeters.xml
- Then, add new task "Replace Tokens" with the specified variable for each environment.

However, i don't guess this will work for me, because it generate tokens only for app settings keys (which is not my case).

Is there is a work around or any other suggestion that could help me to do the configuration part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Replace Tokens" task can works with any config file in your project and what content to be replaced is also controlled by you.

For example, if you want to replace a URL in "myconfig.config" file. You can set the URL in the config file to "#{targeturl}#", and add a "Replace Tokens" task in your definition with the following settings: (You can change the token prefix and suffix, but remember to update it accordingly in the config file since the task find the strings to replace base on it)
[image]

And then create a variable "targeturl" in the definition with the actual URL value:
[image]

Now, when you start the build/release, the string "#{targeturl}#" in "myconfig.config" file will be replaced with "www.test.com".

Comment: Perfect! I will try it. Thanks @Eddie for you supprt

Comment: you are specifying the variables on the build definition. The same value will be replaced for all environments. However, i need different configuration per environment, this is why i need to specify the variable per environment unless there is a reason for build definition variable.

Comment: This worked for me, however the problem now is how I can debug the application locally using my VS 2015? Because if I replace the url by special tokens, the url contains "#{targetUrl}#" which is waiting for another process or task to replace the tokens.

Comment: @h.salman Then you can add a slowcheetah transformation for your config file to use different value in different configuration.

Comment: Actually i want to avoid using transformation. But, if i want to use that, i should put the tokens in the web.config then create a transformation web.debug.config and do the replacement there. But, how can i replace certain tokens in the URL itself. Please, check my new question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217934/web-config-transforms-replacing-a-token-in-wcfendpoint-address]

Comment: Isn't any out of the box solution in RM? trying to modify a config file from a zip archive is pretty tedious..